# SQL - Select integer in complex field (CAST and LIKE operators)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table **TabCustomer** containing a number of fields.

One of these fields is a complex one named **externalUser**:

```
{"id":123,"companyID":12,"name":"Paul","surname":"Smith",...}
```

How can I select all the rows of this tab containing 123 as id;

I tried with CAST this way:

```
 SELECT * from tabCustomer WHERE CAST(externalUser.id AS VARCHAR(6)) LIKE '%id:"123"%'
```

but getting 0 results

Comment: not exactly because for integer, it does not work the previous solution and I need it for integer as well

Comment: @jpw, see here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18462376/1948785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `"` from `LIKE` operator. See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1467a/4

```
LIKE '"id":123%'
```

Your query should look like

```
SELECT * from tabCustomer 
WHERE externalUser LIKE '"id":123%'
```

Comment: thanks but my column looks like this {"id":123,"companyID":12,"name":"Paul","surname":"Smith"} with curly braces

Comment: That should still work with little modification. See the fiddle again http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2a319/2

Comment: this is a kind of workaround though and it should not work if "id" is not in that position, right?

Comment: It will work and you need to place the wildcard characters accordingly but it's never a elegent solution for the kind of data you have in that column. You should think re-designing your table to hold that data (looks like a JSON format data) properly.