# Like condition is not working in JPA @Query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using like condition is JPA, I am facing the issue.

```java
@Query("select new com.tivo.extract.config.model.DTO(s.SourceId, s.SourceName, t.TvsourceLongName) from MyTelevisionSource t join fetch RCMSource s ON s.SourceId = t.SourceId where s.SourceId LIKE ?1% ")
List<DTO> findFilteredSourceList(String seachInput);
```

If i am using `s.SourceId` like `%?1% --> %searchInput% ->` its working

but for `s.SourceId` LIKE `?1% -> searchInput% ->` its not working

`SourceId` column in Long type in DB.

I am getting an **exception**:

```
Parameter value [021%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Parameter value [021%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
```

Comment: Maybe `SourceId` is an number and `seachInput` is some texte ...

Comment: i think it is because source id is Long https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462376/like-operator-for-integer

Comment: @Zorglube, its working if i am giving s.SourceId like %?1%,

can you suggest how to use s.SourceId like ?1%, because i want post search.

Comment: @mohan, you can't use `LIKE` on a number. On a number you can do `>` or `=` or `<`. If oyu whant to do some `LIKE` you have to transform your number on a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play around with `CONCAT`:

```
@Query("select new com.tivo.extract.config.model.DTO(s.SourceId, s.SourceName, t.TvsourceLongName)
        from MyTelevisionSource t join fetch RCMSource s ON s.SourceId = t.SourceId 
        where s.SourceId LIKE CONCAT(?1,'%') ")
    List<DTO> findFilteredSourceList(String seachInput);
```

Comment: CONCAT(?1,'%') always will act as    seachInput%  , but sometime i want to have %seachInput  and i can have %seachInput% also.

For this any suggestion??

Comment: Then you need to add the % at the beginning programmatically.