# SQL query not returning results could Type be the problem?

Tags: php, sql

The DB has a 'transaction' with a value of 217 and another of 1 in the clientID column the date and dateEntered columns have entries from 2021 and 2022.

[image: Screen cap showing DB rows]

The query returns results when I search by date and dateEntered but as soon as the query includes the value for the clientID I get no results.

php:

```
var_dump($params); // This returns the Array shown below
echo('<h2>' . $query . '</h2>'); // This returns the Query shown below

    $query = $this->query($query, $params);
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM`transaction` WHERE `date` LIKE :date AND `dateEntered` LIKE :dateEntered AND `affiliateID` LIKE :affiliateID AND `clientID` LIKE :clientID AND `supplierID` LIKE :supplierID
```

Array:

```
array(5) { ["date"]=> string(4) "%20%" ["dateEntered"]=> string(4) "%20%" ["affiliateID"]=> string(2) "%%" ["clientID"]=> string(5) "%217%" ["supplierID"]=> string(2) "%%" }
```

I've noticed that the array contains type of "string" and the DB is typed as INT, could this be my problem? I've never run into type problems in DB searching before. I make the array with the following code:

```
    $value = '%' . $paramaters['values'][0] . '%';
    $query .= ' `' . $paramaters['column'] . '` LIKE :' . $paramaters['column'] . ' AND';
    $params[$paramaters['column']] = $value;
```

If the typing is my problem, how would I change the type in the array I'm constructing here? If typing is not my problem, where else should I look?

Comment: I don't think you can use `LIKE` with non-string columns, see this for an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462508/231316

Comment: using the following query directly in phpmyadmin I get two results as I expected:
SELECT * FROM `transaction` WHERE `clientID` LIKE '%1%' but I'll try amending the things so the generated query doesn't use LIKE for columns that are INT and see if that fixes things.