# SSRS Single parameter dropdown list to choose between multiple columns

Tags: reporting-services

I want 2 cascading parameters, the 1st needs to be a dropdown (@SearchBy) which would allow the user to choose WHICH column they want to search by: Item, Username, Location. Then a 2nd parameter would be a typed search based on the 1st parameter. I know how to get the 2nd parameter (@SearchFor), but I am struggling to figure out how to set up the dropdown list parameter for separate columns.

It would be easier to set up multiple parameters with null options but this is not what the user wants. The columns do not have distinct values so I cannot set the query to :
WHERE user.name IN (@Search) OR location.num IN (@Search) OR item.type IN (@Search)

Comment: Use `LIKE` instead of `IN`. If one of your search cols [isn't an nvarchar then cast it to one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462508/3585500).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be better ways of doing this but try something like this simplified version..

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE 
    (user.name IN (@Search) AND @SearchBy = 'user.name')
    OR (location.num IN (@Search) AND @SearchBy = 'location.num')
    OR (item.type IN (@Search) AND @SearchBy = 'item.type')
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much. I know it was a basic level issue, I just couldn't wrap my brain around how to set the values for the @Search parameter.